# Pantheon Files F2 bug

Tags: pantheon-files, ubuntu

Since a few weeks whenever I try to rename a file by hitting the F2 key the file selection moves to either the file above or below the one originally selected, and then the name becomes editable.

Specifically, if I navigate to a file with the arrow keys, if the last key was UP, then F2 moves the selections DOWN. If the last key was DOWN, then F2 moves the selection up.

Any clues about what is happening?

I should mention that I'm running Pantheon Files on a Ubuntu 17.10 installation with the Gnome Wayland desktop. But up to a few weeks ago, this problem was NOT present :P

Comment: As the file manager has been installed on a Ubuntu base, it may serve you better to pose this question on Ask Ubuntu rather than here. However, the little I researched this, it looks like the issue could be an argument with keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug/regression that the keyboard focus does not properly follow the selection and there is a couple of fixes awaiting review, merging and release.   The keyboard focus is indicated by highlighting the icon but this may not be obvious for icons that are already light in color.  At the moment it is safest to use the context menu on the item and choose "Rename".